# type is not a subtype of type error in flutter

Tags: flutter, events, calendar

```
class AddEvent extends MyCalendar {
  AddEvent({super.key});

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> events = {
    DateTime.utc(2022, 12, 10): [Event('1'), Event('2'), Event('3')],
    DateTime.utc(2022, 12, 11): [Event('4')],
  };

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _addCalendar() {
    events[DateTime.now()] = Event('123') as List<Event>;
  }
}

class Event {
  String title;
  Event(this.title);
}
```

Hi all!
i'm now in flutter
i'm trying to event add function in caleadar in my app
i run _addCalendar() by click button
but not running

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqmBu.png)

look at my code,,,

Comment: Have you looked at the stacktrace of the error? For this kind of error it's usually very precise on where the problem is. I'm telling you this because it seems that it's expecting a var of type `Error` but I don't see any `Error` in your code

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your trying to add an `Event` to a `List<Event>` inside your map, and you cannot cast a type with a totally different type like this `Event('123') as List<Event>`, you need to do:

```
class AddEvent extends MyCalendar {
  AddEvent({super.key});

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> events = {
    DateTime.utc(2022, 12, 10): [Event('1'), Event('2'), Event('3')],
    DateTime.utc(2022, 12, 11): [Event('4')],
  };

  // ignore: unused_element
  void _addCalendar() {
    final DateTime date = DateTime.now();
    events[date] ??= [];
    events[date] = events[date]!.add(Event('123'));
  }
}

class Event {
  String title;
  Event(this.title);
}
```

Comment: first Thanks your comment
i try yout answer but 'This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.' is alter now...
 this is my call code 
onPressed: () => AddEvent()._addCalendar()
thanks very much bro